# How can I split matrix to some matrices in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a 256*256 Matrix and I want to split it into 16 matrices (64*64). I know I can use `mat2cell`, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) is quite clear:

```
C = mat2cell( M, 64*ones(4,1), 64*ones(1,4) );
```

Comment: @MaziyarGrami So as to elaborate a little to this, you need to specify the matrix dimensions for each cell. Argument 1 is the matrix, argument 2 number of rows for the matrix of each cell, argument 3 number of columns for each cell. So for and m-by-n matrix, `sum(arg2)` is m and `sum(arg3)` is n.